# How to set & get only value string in react-select's state

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have tried following code, but it sets & gets the entire json of the selected value. How to set & get only the `value` of the `selectedOption` & not the entire `json` of the `selectedOption` from `state` after the selection. The code given in the the official documentation is given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please show us what `console.log('Option selected: ' + JSON.stringify(selectedOption));` prints?

Comment: @c-chavez if all the three options are selected, then it prints all three options:

[
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]

Comment: how can 3 options be selected... there should only be one option selected... I'm still missing something with your question. Could you please edit your question and explain a bit more what you need, what is currently happening, and what do you expect from your output?

Comment: there is a option called as `multiselect` available in the `package`

Comment: So, when you have 3 options selected what do you want to show? what is your expected output? If you have a read again at your question, you never mention this... it is different to handle just one object than to handle an array of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to actually make your component wrapper around react-select component example:

```js
const CustomSelect = ({onChange, options, value, isMulti}) => {
  return(
       <Select
            options={options}
            onChange={(val) => isMulti
                ? onChange(val.map((c) => c.value))
                : onChange(val.value)
            }
            value={isMulti
                ? options.filter((c) => value.includes(c.value))
                : options.find((c) => c.value === value)
            }
            isMulti={isMulti}
        />
       )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you should bind `handleChange` in `constructor`

because `react-reselect` by default bind all methods in code line https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/.babelrc#L4

`transform-class-properties` in `.babelrc` bind by default

Do bind like this:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

**And the answer to your question here:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  }
  constructor() {
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    console.log('selectedOption', selectedOption); // log here before set state
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: arrow functions doesnt need bindings

Answer (score -4):

Extract selected value and pass to handler

```
   onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.value)}
```

...

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Select from 'react-select';

    const options = [
      { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
      { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
      { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
    ];

    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        selectedOption: null,
      }
      handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
      }
      render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (
          <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.value)}
            options={options}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: please explain what your code does, what you have changed, so that OP and the rest of the users can understand why is this an answer to the question.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add this info, reading the comments is harder for future viewers.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer?? Please aware of what you are posting and expecting :)